# Question about apostrophe usage with 2 possessors

Tags: grammar

Normally, with a single person owning the object, I would say:
This is Tom's object.

However, if there are 2 people, should I have apostrophes on both subjects or just on the second one?

E.g. These are Tom's and Jane's objects. / These are Tom and Jane's objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll base this answer on another from a different site, who cited *The Grammar Bible* by Michael Strumpf.

Both are valid, but the choice depends on the type of ownership. If the ownership is joint, use the latter:

> These are Tom and Jane's children.

If the ownership is singular and you're discussing multiple ownerships, use the former:

> These are Tom's and Jane's jackets.